# Hide/Show ActionMode while Navigationdrawer opened/closed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, contextual-action-bar

I have a RecyclerView with Cards and i use the Contextual Actionbar
only for one selected Card.

Beside i implemented the NavigationDrawer from support design libary. And when the NavigationDrawer is opened i want to hide the contextual actionbar /and open it when it is closed.

I looked at the same Issue but i cant solve my Problem.
[Here][1]

```
   @Override
   public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
   super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
   mActionMode.finish();
   }
```

With this Method it works fine. I can hide the Actionbar while the ND opened.
But i cant show the CAB after the NavigationDrawer closed

the accepted solution doesn't look all that nice as the ActionMode sits on top of the drawer until it's fully open/close.

So i cant use the onDrawerClosed Method because i must fully close the navigationdrawer.

I hope someone can help me

Comment: please fix the link "[Here][1]" doesn't work; did you eventually solve this somehow?